# How would I fix my diffuse colors not appearing from my High Poly baking object?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, texture-baking

I'm currently attempting to bake down details from a thin string object to a box object so that the box gets the colors and uses less tris than the string. A Simple High Poly to Low Poly bake.

[image: The LP box]
[image: The HP strings]

My problem is whenever I attempt to actually bake this down to an actual image only a few pixels appear and not the full strings as intended. Why might this be happening?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SnS_gtaHHLEojkd-n26nKfCw_SsRcd0r/view?usp=drive_link

A link containing the Blend file.

[image: The result]

Comment: your link is private access

Comment: @lemon I have changed the accessibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The details you want to bake sink under the geometry in a few places. Adjust the details to be slightly above the surface everywhere, and they should show up correctly in the bake.

---

**Edit:** It turned out that the resolution of the destination texture was too low. At 1024, the missing details showed up. However, they showed up in more areas than they should. The fix was to set the *Max Ray Distance* to 0.1 m. A screenshot of the result is shown below.

[image: Bake]

Right now, you need a high texture resolution, because you include large faces in the bake. Maybe you should only have faces that match the rope shape.

Comment: Even when I have it scaled to encase the high poly geometry it still does the same thing

Comment: Okay, I will check if there is an issue with the bake settings when I get the chance.

Comment: I updated my answer with the actual fix.

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Comment: You're welcome!